# SSL Login Structure

Tags: security, ssl, authentication

I have a members only celebrity photo and video gallery, for media professionals only. It's setup on a dedicated server and I have recently installed a wildcard SSL certificate.

I have a main public website which advertises our services, hosts the registrations forms and has the secure login form. The login form, when submitted, goes to the same server but to a different account/directory, like so:

```
From: https://www.mydomain.com/login
To: https://subdomain.mydomain.com/login
```

... and then the login detail get processed.

Does my login page need to be on `https://` when they arrive on it, or does my login form need `action="https://..."` to make it secure? I'm not familiar with how SSL works.

Comment: Familiarity with security is whats important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the landing page that has the login form isn't https,  then attacker can deliver wahtever they want,  and just rewrite the page to http.  [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) is a tool that an attacker can use to perform this attack.

But more importantly,  who cares about the login page?  Sure it should be protected, but a username and password isn't how the browser authenticates.  The browser uses a cookie to authenticate with your web application,  **this is the real authentication token**.  It really doesn't mean anything if you login over https and then just spill the authentication token a few seconds later.  the **entire session must be over https** or you will be violation of [owasp a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).

Comment: So https login form sent to https login processor and then remain on https throughout the entire members area?

Comment: @Martin G If you do that,  then you also have to send a new cookie to the browser.  Because if at any point you spill that value over http, then you are boned.   This new cookie can have the "secure" flag set so that its always transmitted over https.